# springdoc-openapi-ui returning 406 error-not-acceptable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using springdoc-openapi-ui for my web application but when I hit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html in the browser I am getting 406 error code.

Below is the dependency in pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
          <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.14</version>
  </dependency>
```

And Spring Security config is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        return http.build();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
      return web -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**");
  }
```

Spring boot version I am using 2.7.7

Below is network detail via inspect element in chrome for the swagger-ui.config ..
[image]

Comment: It's possible that your models are missing getter/setter ?

Comment: @viglu I am using lombok for getter and setter

Comment: Pls suggest something on this issue